# What happens when a synchronized method is accessed at the same time in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Ok, so I am trying to build a script that will automate some tests on x amount of machines...and I want them all to talk to one another. I am a bit new to thread and I have done some research about using synchronized methods. My question is, what happens when two separate threads try to access it? I understand it locks and gives the caller exclusive access, but then is the next call in line processed directly after it? I could have multiple threads call the same function at the same time and I want to be prepared to handle it. I also found this bit of information:

> When a method is called, the JVM creates a stack frame for the call in
>   the executing thread. This frame contains all of the local variables
>   declared in the method. In the case of any method, static or
>   otherwise, that doesn't access fields, each execution proceeds
>   completely independently on each thread. If the method uses parameters
>   in its calculation, these parameters are also located in the stack
>   frame, and multiple calls don't interfere with each other.

This was said in another post and it was not in reference to a synchronized method. Sorry if I am not making myself clear,  but I just want to make sure what a certain function is called from a thread, that it is treated like a stack.

Comment: Which thread gets access next after the first is up to the Thread scheduler.

Comment: take a look at `fairness` property for multi-threaded environment

Comment: @Ducksauce88, What does Java's "synchronized" keyword have to do with "automate some tests on x machines?"  Are you sure you are asking the right question?  What are you really trying to achieve, and why do you think it's hard?

Comment: It isnt hard....I just want to build it in a way that makes the most sense. Maybe I should have waited to post until I start writing it. It has to nothing to do with the automation...I simply am writing a program that will talk to all pcs running the automation scripts in an attempt to have them run their main test procedure at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a synchronized method, and x threads try to access it at the same time, by magic, only one gets access and the others just wait (block) until the one that has access is finished with it. If the thread that is allowed inside the synchronized method never exits the block, you have what is called a deadlock.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like I should nix using synchronized...would you suggest not using it all together? You are correct, the chances of that happening are very slim...this isn't going to be a very intuitive script. Basically I want all computer to sit and wait at a certain point, then when all computers are at the correct point, execute the test case. I am automating downloads for some cell phones....maybe I should have mentioned that earlier. Sorry, I'm all over the place.

Comment: @monkjack,  A Deadlock is when you have two or more threads, and _none_ of them is making progress because each of them is waiting for one (or more) of the others to do something first.  What you have described is called "starvation."  That's when one thread is running, monopolizing a resource, and preventing other threads that want the same resource from running.

Comment: @monkjack, Be careful!  Java synchronization does not necessarily prevent more than one thread from entering the same synchronized method or block at the same time:  It prevents two or more threads from synchronizing _on the same object_ at the same time.

Comment: @jameslarge re: starvation, I had in my head the scenario you describe, where the threads are not making progress. I concede my wording was vague, but I feel it was in line with the original posters knowledge level.